# Suavizar serrilhado no degrade

Tags: css

Estou usando degrade no CSS, mas fica um serrilhado, tem alguma forma de suavizar via CSS?

```css
p {
  background-image: linear-gradient(161.2deg, green 50%, white 50%, white);
}
```

```html
<p>Gradiente</p>
```

Comment: No Chrome fica mais visivel o serrilhado, no firefox a visualização está um pouco melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da maneira que esta o serrilhado ira existir pois `50%`/`50%` não é aplicado o degradê, pois não existe a transição, mas se a diferença for de `0.05%`, já melhora o resultado, pois um pouco de degradê será aplicado.

Olha como ficaria:

```css
p {
  background-image: linear-gradient(161.2deg, green 49.5%, white 50%, white);
}
```

```html
<p>Gradiente</p>
```

Comment: Boa saída, mas o serrilhado não existiria se o navegador decidisse usar mais profundidade de cor. Isso feito no Photoshop não dá serrilhado.

Comment: Legal para esse caso resolve o problema, porém estou fazendo um timer que preenche o degrade conforme a posição, não posso usar imagens,é tudo via css, em outros casos não rolou fazer essa alteração.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, eu sugiro mudar o código para...

```
p {
  background: linear-gradient(161.2deg, green 50%, white 50%, white);
}
```

...sem o -image. Mas imagino que não seja essa a causa. Os navegadores, tradicionalmente, economizam cores para ganhar desempenho e se adaptar a realidade de cada sistema onde rodam. Já melhorou muito em relação aos primórdios com 256 cores, mas um degradê complexo só funcionará bem mesmo com uma aceleração GPU, e não há como controlar isso.

O que eu vi o povo fazer é trocar o degradê renderizado em tempo real por uma imagem de fundo equivalente.

```
p {
background: url('degradeperfeito.png');
}
```

As imagens são melhor renderizadas e o resultado final é melhor. For isso, talvez um CSS4 venha com algum parâmetro de qualidade de renderização, por enquanto só o hack mesmo!

Comment: Imagens geram um resultado melhor mesmo, mas no meu caso não posso é um timer que vai preenchendo conforme a porcentagem, precisa ser uma solução em css mesmo, valeu.